Convergence of finite-difference method for Cauchy-Riemann equations
Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ an open interval. Let $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ real analytic. Suppose we want to numerically compute an analytic extension of $f$.
We will assume the following: we are given an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f$ can be extended over $I \times (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$.
My question is: does finite-difference method (FDM) for Cauchy-Riemann equations inside $I \times (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ converge to the analytic extension?
I tried to use the Lax equivalence theorem, but don't see an obvious way to prove stability.
Motivation: I suppose the simplest way to compute the extension is using power series. However, my motivation is not to find an efficient algorithm. I am self-learning complex analysis and I observed that finite-difference method gives a clear geometric picture of how to extend $f$ (contrary to the power series approach). Thus, I wanted to know if FDM indeed gives the right answer.
